# Smooth horizontal wheel only scrolling

Tags: javascript, scroll, smooth-scrolling

It is very annoing to hold shift when wheeling for horizontal scrolling.
There are some ways to horizontally scrool with wheel only but they directly copy wheel `deltaY` into `scrollLeft` which results in uncomfortable jump-scrolling.

Is there a mobile-friendly way to perform **smooth** horizontal scrolling on elements using wheel only? By "smooth" I mean something like default browser vertical wheel scroll behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Smooth scrolling can be achieved by using [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

You might want to play with denominator in `getScrollStep` function to adjust the smoothness of scrolling.

```js
function horizontalWheel(container) {
  /** Max `scrollLeft` value */
  let scrollWidth;

  /** Desired scroll distance per animation frame */
  let getScrollStep = () => scrollWidth / 50 /* ADJUST TO YOUR WISH */ ;

  /** Target value for `scrollLeft` */
  let targetLeft;

  function scrollLeft() {
    let beforeLeft = container.scrollLeft;
    let wantDx = getScrollStep();
    let diff = targetLeft - container.scrollLeft;
    let dX = wantDx >= Math.abs(diff) ? diff : Math.sign(diff) * wantDx;

    // Performing horizontal scroll
    container.scrollBy(dX, 0);

    // Break if smaller `diff` instead of `wantDx` was used
    if (dX === diff)
      return;

    // Break if can't scroll anymore or target reached
    if (beforeLeft === container.scrollLeft || container.scrollLeft === targetLeft)
      return;

    requestAnimationFrame(scrollLeft);
  }

  container.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    scrollWidth = container.scrollWidth - container.clientWidth;
    targetLeft = Math.min(scrollWidth, Math.max(0, container.scrollLeft + e.deltaY));

    requestAnimationFrame(scrollLeft);
  });
}
```

Just pass elements you want to horizontally scroll with wheel in this function:

```js
let list = document.querySelector('.hList');
horizontalWheel(list);
```

Example:

```js
function horizontalWheel(container) {
  /** Max `scrollLeft` value */
  let scrollWidth;

  /** Desired scroll distance per animation frame */
  let getScrollStep = () => scrollWidth / 50 /* ADJUST TO YOUR WISH */ ;

  /** Target value for `scrollLeft` */
  let targetLeft;

  function scrollLeft() {
    let beforeLeft = container.scrollLeft;
    let wantDx = getScrollStep();
    let diff = targetLeft - container.scrollLeft;
    let dX = wantDx >= Math.abs(diff) ? diff : Math.sign(diff) * wantDx;

    // Performing horizontal scroll
    container.scrollBy(dX, 0);

    // Break if smaller `diff` instead of `wantDx` was used
    if (dX === diff)
      return;

    // Break if can't scroll anymore or target reached
    if (beforeLeft === container.scrollLeft || container.scrollLeft === targetLeft)
      return;

    requestAnimationFrame(scrollLeft);
  }

  container.addEventListener('wheel', e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    scrollWidth = container.scrollWidth - container.clientWidth;
    targetLeft = Math.min(scrollWidth, Math.max(0, container.scrollLeft + e.deltaY));

    requestAnimationFrame(scrollLeft);
  });
}

//
// Usage
//

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let list = document.querySelector('.hList');
  horizontalWheel(list);
});
```

```css
.hList {
  width: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.element {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 150px;
  height: 75px;
  background: green;
  border-right: 2px solid yellow;
}

.element:last-of-type {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="hList">
  <div class="element">Element 1</div>
  <div class="element">Element 2</div>
  <div class="element">Element 3</div>
  <div class="element">Element 4</div>
  <div class="element">Element 5</div>
</div>
```